# How to set cookie value properly with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php

I have a Google AdWords campaign, so when users click on the ad it links them to a certain page. The page URL has a specific Google Ad string, so using it, I want to change some colors on all pages, not only one.

I'm trying to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `setcookies()` function. Let's say that the Google Ad string is `adword`. So when the ad was clicked it linked to https://example.com/adword/ page and I get this slug string and set to cookies a value:

```
$cookie_val = '';
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "adword") && !isset($_COOKIE['ad_cookies'])){
    setcookie('ad_cookies', 'myvalue', time()+(3600*6));  /* expire in 6 hours */
    $cookie_val = $_COOKIE['ad_cookies'];
}
```

I though then I can use this cookie value everywhere, for example by changing class name of a div:

```
<div class="page <?php echo $cookie_val ?>">
```

But it only works on one page https://example.com/adword/.

So my question is, how can I use this cookie value on every page when a user clicked the ad? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you consider the session instead

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to use cookies for it.

Comment: Then look at the `path` parameter in `setcookie` [Here is a link to the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) probably should have started there to be honest

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you mean I should add '/' in the path parameter? I tried, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Where else are you trying to use this cookie (exactly)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using WordPress on a live website. I guess the path parameter was an issue. Now everything is working when I use incognito mode for a live website. But it doesn't work when I logged in. So you can write an answer and I will mark it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, lets put it down to a Should have read the manual :)